# Python run an executable file in python using subprocess windows 10

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run massdns.exe which is in the same folder as my python file

```
subprocess.run("dir", shell=True)
```

output

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A6AB-C832

 Directory of C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\folder1\folder2\massdns

02/02/2020  07:59 PM           251,991 massdns.exe
```

as you can see, it's in the same folder.

when I try doing `subprocess.run(".\massdns.exe -r lists/resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt generated_domains.txt", shell=True)` it does nothing. While, in the command line window or while in the powershell window, it runs the program as expected.

Things I have tried     subprocess.check_output("massdns.exe -r lists/resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt generated_domains.txt", shell=True)

`subprocess.run(".\massdns.exe -r lists/resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt 
generated_domains.txt", shell=True)`

When I do this

```
subprocess.check_output("massdns.exe -r lists/resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt generated_domains.txt", shell=True)
```

I get this error

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'massdns.exe -r lists/resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt generated_domains.txt' returned non-zero exit status 3221225781.
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash character?

Comment: Like this? `subprocess.check_output("massdns.exe -r lists\\resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt generated_domains.txt", shell=True)` Just tried it and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The backslash, not forward slash.
`'.\\massdns.exe -r lists/resolvers.txt -t AAAA -w results.txt generated_domains.txt'`

Comment: Ah I see, just tried, still doesn't work I also just tried `import os` `os.system("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\massdns\\massdns.exe")` and nothing printed, when I think it should have printed the flags that are required when you use the massdns.exe program..

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem, which would have been really hard to answer if you weren't in the same room as me. I'm using pycharm and I moved the massdns.exe file into another folder (the same folder I was trying to execute it in python though) and I didn't close my pycharm's command line, which I guess somehow messes with it, I closed pycharm alltogether and ta-da it worked.